# Neural Networks in Python without using any readymade libraries...i.e., from first principles..help!

Tags: python, scipy, neural-network

I am trying to learn programming in python and am also working against a deadline for setting up a neural network which looks like it's going to feature multidirectional associative memory and recurrent connections among other things. While the mathematics for all these things can be accessed from various texts and sources (and is accessible, so to speak), as a newbie to python (and programming as a profession) I am kinda floating in space looking for the firmament as I try to 'implement' things!! 
Information on any good online tutorials on constructing neural networks ab initio will be greatly appreciated :)

In the meantime I am moonlighting as a MatLab user to nurse the wounds caused by Python :)

Comment: if you're a Matlab user, why implement in python? Matlab (and Octave, Matlab's free-software brother) is a very nice tool for NN.

Comment: todA :), I do prefer Matlab...but Python's freeware...and learning it seems like a good option if it can help solve the same class of problems...only all the OOP stuff is unfamiliar and Matlab looks more attractive with each passing day

Comment: Here's an 'ab initio' three-layer perceptron implementation that i've studied and used (excellent IMHO):
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-neural/

Answer (score 4):

If you're familiar with Matlab, check out the excellent Python libraries **numpy**, **scipy**, and **matplotlib**. Together, they provide the most commonly used subset of Matlab functions.

Comment: Thanks...I do have these...and have also played with pybrain, PyRo and Monte...but I'm not comfortable with readymate kits...and I am exploring SciPy (it does support lotsa cool functions...but isn;t Matlab more user-friendly?)

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [Neurolab](http://neurolab.googlecode.com) - neural networks in Python with an API like the Neural Networks Toolbox from MATLAB

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about neural networks, but [PyNeurGen](http://pyneurgen.sourceforge.net/recurrent.html) seems like a good resource.

Comment: Thanks Ned,
                 I am lookin' up the PyNeurGen site even as I type (not exactly, but y;know what I mean)